# Read Azure service config .cscfg file in C++

Tags: c++, azure, iis-7, azure-web-roles

I have only been able to find documentation about how to access the ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg file to read configuration values in my WebRole application hosted on the Azure Cloud Service. How can I read these service configuration values if my application is in C++? Are there any examples I can follow?

How can I use the following function in C++:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.getconfigurationsettingvalue.aspx